# Early spring vs. An early spring

Tags: articles

As far as I know, we say: "It was early spring." (the words "late", "early" are not the reason for using the indefinite article there).

But here is another example: "Get ready for an early spring!", with the article.

So my question is whether the article depends on a syntactic function of these words. In the first case, the word is a part of the predicate, in the second one it is a descriptive attribituve.

Thanks.

Comment: It's the same with other time periods. Things change when you introduce an adjective, so ***Prepare for winter!*** is fine (as is *Prepare for **the** winter!*), but whereas *Prepare for **a** cold winter!* is fine, it's not idiomatic to say *Prepare for cold winter!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have it backward: the presence of the article determines [in both the grammatical and the ordinary sense] the interpretation of *early spring*.

> It was early spring (when) ...

Here *spring* acts as a temporal locative designating the timespan during which an action (which will probably be described next) occurs. *Early* is a modifier restricting the reference to the early part of that timespan. You might paraphrase this as *It was early in spring {that) ...*

> It was an early spring ...

Here the determiner *an* excludes our understanding of *spring* as a locative: we are speaking of the season and its characteristics. *Early* is a modifier characterizing this particular season as one which fell earlier than usual in the year. You might paraphrase this as *Spring had arrived early.*

So "Get ready for an early spring!" means literally "Be prepared for spring to arrive early this year".

However, this looks to me like advertising copy, and I suspect that what the copywriter really means (but carefully avoids saying) is "Start buying your spring wardrobe now!"